# Broken link on 'A Culture of Trust' blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, broken-link

The latest blog post entry titled '[A Culture of Trust](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/culture-of-trust/)' by author Arie Litovsky contains a broken link in the para that says:

> Having spent a year and a half on the mobile team, I recently [decided
> to change teams](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/culture-of-trust/blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/going-from-mobile-back-to-the-web/), eventually finding a balance of fit and interest in
> our Careers product.

The '**decided to change teams**' link [currently wrongly](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/culture-of-trust/blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/going-from-mobile-back-to-the-web/) points to:
`https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/culture-of-trust/blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/going-from-mobile-back-to-the-web/`

however the [*correct* URL](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/going-from-mobile-back-to-the-web/) is:

`https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/going-from-mobile-back-to-the-web/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pushed [a fix](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/commit/2bc968b36ad355b7b6492ee073f0c90902cf2547#diff-b80af2e6ffc5855a618ce3e2e995425b) to the blog and triggered a build to push it live.

Granted, you couldn't trigger a build yourself, but this is a good time to remind folks that the blog is open source, including all post content, so if you find a broken link, you could potentially help us fix it by submitting a pull request in the time it'd take you to write a meta post reporting the problem. :)

Comment: Sure, will submit the pull request from here onwards. Thank you.